How did Alexander The Great defeat Darius III?
I know that Alexander's skills (militarily, leadership-wise, diplomatically)  and  Darius' weaknesses (as a leader, as a military strategist, as a king in general) combined to give Alexander control of the Persian empire at the end of the Persian campaign from 334-331 BC. I got this from reading Plutarch's Lives (the Alexander Chapter), and I'm planning to read Arrian's Anabasis.
However, is there a third factor that led to the fall of Persia but was not within Alexander's or Darius' control? Could it be satrapal feuds? Or battle terrains? Or maybe the efforts of Philip? Please let me know what you think. It would also be very helpful if your sources are quoted so I can look at them (I don't doubt anyone, rather, I would appreciate some direction in researching for this topic).
In this case, Wikipedia only glosses over the events. I have not yet undertaken extensive research, but I know that different authors have different opinions. What I want to know is where to start.

Requests for opinions are better suited for discussion sites.  H:SE is a Q&A site and every question should have an Authoritative answer.  As a courtesy, all questions should show research and OP should not comment, but should update the question.  All the information that OP knows, should be in the question, and it should be possible to understand the question and begin research without reading the comments.

To clarify, I think I would just like people to answer my question properly. Why is my background research not enough to ask such a question? Are you perhaps able to summarise why Alexander > Darius III? (I would really appreciate) It's a completely legitimate question. Or rather, to be more specific, to what extent was the fall of the Persian empire caused by Darius' weakness?

ACOUP questions Alexander's skills.

Move the comment into the question.  Discussion in comments is a quick road to question closure.

Thanks for telling me, I'm new here. And thanks for helping me edit. I appreciate it.

The Greeks had for generations been held back by Persian gold rather than Persian arms, so I'm not sure why anyone would be surprised at the Persians getting defeated by the best army in Greece when a fight between them finally happened.
